# What is the derivative of $f(tx)$ with respect to $t$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I think is a super basic question but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how think about this.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. We fix an $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and define the function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(t) = f(tx), \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, my question is what is $g'(t)$? If I were deriving $f(tx)$ with respect to $x$, this is easy, I have $f'(tx)t$, but it's not really clear how to derive with respect to $t$.

Is it $f'(tx)x = \nabla f(tx)x$? If yes, why? Wouldn't that imply that $g'(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, since $f'(tx) =\nabla f(tx) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

I apologize if this a super basic question and I'm just missing something crucial!

**EDIT:** Ok, I think I have an understanding now. Here's what I have:

Let $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, h(t) = tx$. Now, we have $g(t) = f(h(t))$, and so, by the chain rule:

\begin{align}
Dg(t) & = Df(h(t))\cdot Dh(t) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial h_1(t)} & \dots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial h_n(t)}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial t} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial h_n}{\partial t}\end{pmatrix} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\partial f}{\partial h_1(t)}\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial t} + \dots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial h_n(t)}\frac{\partial h_n}{\partial t} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\partial f}{\partial h_1(t)}x_1 + \dots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial h_n(t)}x_n = \frac{\partial f}{\partial tx_1}x_1 + \dots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial tx_n}x_n = Df(tx)x.
\end{align}

Is this understanding correct? Moreover, is $\nabla f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\end{pmatrix}$ or $\nabla f(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + \dots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}$? I thought it was the latter, which led to my confusion, but dealing with everything in jacobian form, it seems that it is the former?

Comment: $g'(t)=\nabla f(tx)\cdot x$

Comment: You can define two maps, and then you apply the chain rule to them, to get the derivative of $g$.  
Let $h\colon \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, which maps every $t\in \mathbb{R}$ to $tx\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @GuyFsone But $\nabla f(tx) \in \mathbb{R}$ while $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, right? So, then this suggests that $g'(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but how is that possible, when $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @J.Salieri If $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, h(t) = tx$ then I have $g(t) = f(h(t))$. Differentiating, I get $g'(t) = f'(h(t))h'(t) = \nabla f(tx)x$ as suggested above. But I don't see how this makes sense considering the issue I'm facing in my above comment.

Comment: The point is that $f'$ doesn´t really exist, what you can define is $df$ which is a map that assigns to each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the linear map $df_x \colon \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So now, $g=f\circ h$. By the chain rule $dg_t=df_{tx} \circ dh_{t}$. This is an equality of linear maps. But if you apply them to $1\in\mathbb{R}$ you get the following equality:
$$g'(t)=dg_{t}(1)=df_{tx}(dh_{t})(1)=df_{tx}(h'(t))=\nabla f(tx)x,$$
where you have used that for a map $f$ which takes real values, $\nabla f(x)=df_{x}$, and that $h'(t)=x$.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I think I understand now, could you please take a look at my edit and let me know if my understanding is correct? Thank you!

Comment: The gradient is a vector, not a scalar.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ok, perfect. That makes everything make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for sake of completeness and other users who will ask something similar; Suppose we are given a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t $g \in \textbf{dom}(f)$ and $h$ is also diff'ble. Then we can apply that chain rule,

$$ \frac{d}{dt} (f (h(t)) = \nabla f(h(t)) \cdot h'(t)$$

Here $h(t) = \textbf{x}t$ and so by the above,

\begin{align*} \frac{d}{dt} f(h(t)) &= \nabla f(h(t)) \cdot h'(t)  \\ \\ & = \nabla f (\textbf{x}t) \cdot \textbf{x}\end{align*}