# Derivative of $f(tx,ty,tz)$ using multivariable chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I would like to find the derivative $\frac{df(tx,ty,tz)}{dt}$ of $f(tx,ty,tz)$ using multivariable chain rule and would really appreciate it if someone could guide me to the more general rule for when the input variables themselves are not concrete(e.g. I know how to find partial derivatives of  $f(x,y,z)=...$ but the $f(tx,ty,tz)$ form threw me, but equally I wouldn't know what to do if we had $f(e^x,\sin(ty),\frac{1}{z})$). What I was thinking was

$$\def\p{\partial} \frac{df(tx,ty,tz)}{dt}=\frac{\p f(tx,ty,tz)}{\p x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\text{similar y and z terms}$$ because this is the definition of the chain rule so I don't see why it wouldnt be this. Of course, this entirely ignores what goes on in the function inputs, so it cannot realistically be correct.

Thanks

Comment: You are correct, the difference here is that the $x$ in $\partial x$ and $dx$ don't mean the same $x$ that appears inside the function next to $t$. Really the $x$s on the outside mean $1$, or the derivative with respect to the first argument, whatever that argument may be. Would this notation $$\partial_tf(ty,tx) = \partial_1f \cdot y + \partial_2f\cdot x = yf_x(ty,tx)+xf_y(ty,tx)$$ make it clearer?

Comment: It is simpler to note that a function of one variable $f(x)$ where $x=x(t)$, then $\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516997/what-is-the-derivative-of-ftx-with-respect-to-t

Comment: @NinadMunshi What are the $y$ and $x$ in the first inequality? I guess $y=\partial_x 1$ but why do we go in the alphabetic order "Differentiate input 1 wrt x  in the first term then wrt y in the second" could I not argue the other way around?

Comment: That's just how the notation convention goes. I deliberately swapped the order to show that the inside function doesn't matter

Comment: @NinadMunshi Could you possibly clarify in words what $\partial_1$ means, I think I misunderstand it to mean "$\partial_{ty}$"

Comment: Yes that interpretation is correct. $\partial_1$ does mean the derivative w.r.t. the first argument. Mathematicians will usually take that to mean $\partial_x$ where $x$ refers to the first argument, regardless of what's inside.